# rotate kinematic cube with vive trigger, vrtk plugin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive, vrtk

I know this question is kinda noob but I really need help with my project. I want to make a test application for VR using VIVE. I'm using Unity3D. I am able to grab a cube using VRTK and I change my grabbing control to grip_press. I only have one VIVE controller currently.

Questions:

1. I want to make player/user to grab the object and place it on a table. After user has placed the object;

[Option 1]:

the grab script will be disable and rotate script will be enable allowing user to press trigger and move left/right to rotate the object like OnMouseDrag example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3pjBQObC90

[Option 2]:

user grab object by trigger press and rotate cube by grip button. How to achieve this if I only one a particular object to be use by grip while other usable objects by trigger_press?

[Option 3]:

grab script will be disable and when the VIVE controller touches the object user can just move left/right to rotate the object.

Which options would be easy to execute?

2. I would like to know whether it is possible to teleport and use the pointer to rotate the cube. In VRTK tutorial it shows you can teleport and grab object, but i want to rotate the cube like in whirlygig, 019_Controller_InteractingWithPointer while able to teleport.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please edit and simply your question

Comment: I already edit, sorry for the confusion. I'm very new to this. Thank you for the advice. Hope you can help me. @MohammadFaizanKhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In relation to your section question. Yes it's possible to have the pointer call the use action and also allow you to teleport.

The example scene you mention uses the `Pointer activates use action` setting on the Interactable Object (as in that setting is ticked).

If you untick that setting, and tick on the pointer script the `Interact with objects` setting.

Then when you put your pointer over something, it won't automatically activate it but it will activate when you press your use button (e.g. your trigger).

Comment: Thank you! would you know how to highlight the controller button and the object when the controller is in touch with the object. For example, when the controller touch grab-able object, the trigger button will be highlighted? For the object, how to highlight only the outline of the object?

Sorry for asking too many questions. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Take a look at the example scene "035_Controller_OpacityAndHighlighting" it has demonstrations of highlighting the controller elements. As for highlighting objects you can just set the highlight colour on the interactable object and it will highlight. If you want to do outline highlighting you just need to specify the outline highlighter too.

Comment: i see, i will take a look on the example. Thank you so much for your time.